# How to implement an add and remove to favorite button in android using menu item

Tags: android, contextmenu, menuitem

I am working on a project where I am required to implement a menu item where the icon needs to change based upon user click. Users can set the item as favorite or remove It if it is already the favorite. These changes also need to be updated on the Room Database. Below is my current code.

```
        @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.myMenu = menu;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_favorite, myMenu);
        favItem = myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_favorite);
        //set different icon when isFavorite is true.
        if (isFavorite){
            favItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_dark);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu: favoriteItemIcon is checked");
        }
//        menu.getItem(R.id.action_favorite);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_favorite:
            updateFavoriteStatus();
                break;
            case  android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void updateFavoriteStatus(){
        if (isFavorite){
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    " "your favorite is set ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            mTeaDetailViewModel.setFavorite(false);
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    " Favourite is Removed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            favItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border);

        }
    }
```

Here is my Dao Class

```
@WorkerThread
@Query("UPDATE my_table SET favorite =:favValue  WHERE name = :name")
void updateFavorite(String name, boolean favValue);
```

I want whenever I click the menu item, the value for the isFavorite row should be updated to either true or false. 
Currently what is working is that I can only update the isFavorite row once, that is set it to true. I am not able to reset it to false when I click the menu item for the second time.

Comment: so what's the issue?

Comment: I need a way I can update values once I click the menu item. At the moment it checks if Item is clicked once. the value cannot change when the favorite value is already true

Answer (score 0):

I have finally cracked it. This is how I did it.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.myMenu = menu;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_favorite, myMenu);
        favItem = myMenu.findItem(R.id.action_favorite);
        //set different icon when isFavorite is true.
        if (isFavorite){
            favItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_dark);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu: favoriteItemIcon is checked");
        }
//        menu.getItem(R.id.action_favorite);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id==R.id.action_favorite){
            if (isFavorite){
                mTeaDetailViewModel.setFavorite(false);
                favItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border);
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        " Favourite is Removed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                mTeaDetailViewModel.setFavorite(true);
                favItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_dark);
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "  favorite set successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I noticed I needed to first check if the item is clicked and then whenever an Item is clicked I am checking the isFavorite status and update accordingly.   If already the item is your favourite when clicked the value is set to false and vice versa By doing this I am able to switch between true and false any time I click the item.
I hope my answer will help someone.